# Loading CPU Registers

Tags: algorithm, cpu, fetch, scheduling, cpu-registers

Imagine CPU burst time is 5ms,the process P1 instructions has loaded in registers.
I want to know during this 5ms the CPU just work with these instruction which are in registers or fetch instruction from RAM to registers several times.

I want to know,fetching instructions from RAM to registers happens one time at this period(5ms) or several times.

Edited:I am talking a bout a one CPU with one core.

Thanks a lot.

Comment: This question seems to come from a parallel universe, the premise makes no sense

Comment: well, maybe theres some sort of emulator for this kind of analysis. But in general this question isn't exactly making sense, since it's highly hard- and software dependent.

Comment: Instructions are not "loaded in registers". Instruction are continuously fetched from memory to the instruction decode logics. Fetches take more or less time depending if they are in the instruction cache or not. In 5 ms, several million fetches are performed.

Comment: I don't see any algorithm involved, let alone mentioned, yet algorithm is the first tag. In the first sentence, are you talking about a processor or a `process`? It would be easier to make even an educated guess what registers are involved if you narrowed down what type of processor you are pondering over.

Comment: During 5ms at any reasonable frequency and IPC, you should expect a few billions of instructions. I hardly think there's any room to store them anywhere, especially not in registers, nor is there a reason to do so. I think you should explain your question better, are you talking about caching code?